# solving linear system with inequality constraints in R

Tags: r

I would like to know how to solve a system of linear equations with constraints (constraints of positivity, negativity and equality) with R. I searched I do not find.

[image]

Comment: Look for documentation on function `?solve`,the package `linprog` and the reason for above comment is this [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You have 12 variables and 7 equality constraints so there is no unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

think you for your answers.
I think I have forgotten  some precisions on the exogenous variables.
I have corrected the question.`[enter image description here][1]`